# Finding most results in a category and connecting it to another category in a separate table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return a result of the Student Name who is enrolled in the most sections from the Is_Registered_T table.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sTiq.png)

```
Student
Student_ID  Student_Name
12365       Kayla
38214       LetterSky
45874       Michael
54907       Altvater
66324       Aiken
70542       Marra
78412       Jennifer
78457       Kim
78478       Steve
78548       Kristy
78596       Eddie
78956       Christ
86582       Dianne
89547       Agnes
89754       Mary

Is_Registered
Student_ID  Setion_ID  Semester
12365       2723       I-2001
38214       2714       I-2001
38214       2723       I-2002
45874       2714       I-2002
45874       2716       I-1999
45874       2722       I-2001
54907       2714       I-2001
54907       2715       I-2001
54907       2720       I-2003
66324       2713       I-2001
66324       2719       I-1999
66324       2722       I-2001
66324       2725       I-2000
70542       2720       I-1998
70542       2728       I-1999
78596       2723       I-2000
86582       2725       I-2003
89547       2712       I-2002
89547       2713       I-1999
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I have used an INTO function below to create a separate table, and I can return the most records (4) but not the name of the student (Aiken). Is there a simpler solution?

```
Select Student_Name, Count(Section_ID) Sections_Enrolled
from Student_t, IS_Registered_t
where Student_t.Student_ID = IS_Registered_t.Student_ID
group by Student_Name

Student_Name Sections_Enrolled
------------ -----------------
Agnes        2
Aiken        4
Altvater     3
Dianne       1
Eddie        1
Kayla        1
LeterSky     2
Marra        2
Michael      3
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: `INTO` isn't a function, it's a operator; specifically a DDL and DML operator, as it both `CREATE`s a table and then `INSERT`s data into it.

Comment: What's wrong withh the query shown?

Comment: The query shown returns the entire table. I need to return the name of Aiken, since it has the most enrolled sections @Kendle

Comment: @larnu What would be the easiest way to return the result of the Student Name with the most sections enrolled given the picture of the tables provided?

Comment: What should happen if two students both have 4 enrolments? Do you just want the name o the student(s) or also their id, and/or any other columns? Do you need to know how many or which enrolments they have?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use-case, you could:

1. Get all students with the number of enrollments equal to the maximum number of enrollments (i.e. if there are multiple students which enrolled 4 times, you would return all of them)
2. Order students by the number of enrollments and take the first one (if multiple students have the same number of enrollments, an arbitrary student would be chosen)

#### Solution 1.1 (preferred)

Uses [Top with ties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) and produces a simpler execution plan

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES s.Student_Name, COUNT(*) AS Sections_Enrolled
FROM Student s JOIN Is_Registered r ON s.Student_ID = r.Student_ID
GROUP BY s.Student_ID, s.Student_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

#### Solution 1.2 - "manual"

Not preferred, produces a more complex execution plan. The innermost query counts the sections enrolled; the one-upper-level query finds the maximum number of the sections enrolled; the outmost query once more counts the sections enrolled, and filters the result to include only those which are equal to the previously found max number

```
SELECT s.Student_Name, COUNT(*) AS Sections_Enrolled
FROM Student s JOIN Is_Registered r ON s.Student_ID = r.Student_ID
GROUP BY s.Student_ID, s.Student_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = -- number of sections enrolled equals to the maximum number of sections enrolled
          (SELECT MAX(c.Sections_Enrolled)
          FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Sections_Enrolled
               FROM Student s JOIN Is_Registered r ON s.Student_ID = r.Student_ID
               GROUP BY s.Student_ID) c)
```

#### Solution 2

```
SELECT TOP 1 s.Student_Name, COUNT(*) AS Sections_Enrolled
FROM Student s JOIN Is_Registered r ON s.Student_ID = r.Student_ID
GROUP BY s.Student_ID, s.Student_Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you just want the name, you can remove the `COUNT(*) AS Sections_Enrolled` from the outmost query.

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=043abccbf4458e531ff72d6391dba2e2)

Comment: Probably should use WITH TIES, and/or explain in the answer the behaviour if multiple students are tied for the highest number of enrolments... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0839fafacb9eec8fecc3203c6e69ff8b

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a need for the inner join inside the subquery.

```
SELECT
    MIN(s.Student_Name) AS Name,
    COUNT(*) AS Sections_Enrolled
FROM Student s INNER JOIN 
    Is_Registered r ON s.Student_ID = r.Student_ID
GROUP BY s.Student_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Is_Registered
    GROUP BY Student_ID
);
```

Or extra-succinct:

```
with summary as (select Student_ID, count(*) cnt from Is_Registered group by Student_ID)
select (select Student_Name from Students where Student_ID = s.Student_ID) as Student_Name, cnt
from summary s where cnt = (select max(cnt) from summary);
```